# ASP.NET with Unity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, unity-container, webforms

Can anyone help point me to some good resources for working with Unity 2.0 in an ASP.NET that doesn't talk about ASP.NET MVC?!?

We are not using MVC and I am struggling to get Unity to inject dependencies into my pages following the couple of examples I've read (which are all based on David Hayden's work so they are all presenting the same examples and code).

**UPDATE**

I tried to go the PageHandlerFactory route but the example ([here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/willemm/archive/2009/10/19/inversion-of-control-of-asp-net-pages-using-unity.aspx)) is incomplete and no source code is available to accompany the article.

So, I decided to try the custom HttpModule approach described [here](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/19/Unity-dependency-injection-for-ASPNet.aspx) and [here](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/UnityAspWebDependencyInjectionGuestsAutofacNinject.aspx).  Again, no source code is available beyond what is shown so it is difficult to troubleshoot issues.

The problem I have now is that all of the plumbing appears to be wiring up correctly but the Buildup method does nothing to my page.  I can see all of the types are registered in the container when I set a break-point in the module code and the code is executing as expected.  But a break-point in the Page_Load event handler shows that the dependencies are all null.

The property in question is public, with a setter and getter, and is marked with the Dependency attribute.  I've tried with and without the attribute, with and without a mapping name, ... every combination I could think of and nothing works.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you expect. Most exemples targeting MVC present custom controller factory which allows creating controllers with dependency injection. This is indeed also possible with web forms but instead of controller you must inject dependencies into pages. To do this you must replace `PageHandlerFactory` with custom implementation.

You can create your own implementation of `PageHandlerFactory` which will be able to resolve pages directly and inject dependencies defined in constructor or you can use one of these ([here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/willemm/archive/2009/10/19/inversion-of-control-of-asp-net-pages-using-unity.aspx), [here](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/19/Unity-dependency-injection-for-ASPNet.aspx) and [here](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/27542?ProjectName=unity)) which instead uses stantandard `PageHandlerFactory` and builds page instance (resolve property dependencies).

Comment: I finally noticed the link at the bottom of the first example and compared the implementation to mine.  Once I fixed a small type-o - I used BuildUp(object) instead of BuildUp(Type, object) - I was in business.  The PageHandlerFactory route seems to be perfect.  It's clean and can be plugged in through config which is desired.  Thanks!